# Avoid image to get streteched when used as background image, in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am developing a website in flex. 
And in that, i am trying to set the background image of my application. 
like this:
parentApplication.setStyle("backgroundImage", data.image_src);

From a different location.

My issue is that, the images that i have are small and hence they are being stretched when used as background images. 
I want to avoid that from happening. How can i do it?

Please help me with the issue.

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`backgroundSize`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Container.html#style:backgroundSize) property to "auto" or to a fixed size.

> The default for the Application
>   container is 100%. The default value
>   for all other containers is auto,
>   which maintains the original size of
>   the image.

If you want to tile instead, look at [this post](http://blog.creacog.co.uk/2007/06/11/tile-or-repeat-an-image-into-a-flex-application-background-ii/).